# How to read properties of a class in a given order?

Tags: matlab

I have a coordinate class definition. I need to read the properties in an order of "west, east, north, south". The properties() will read the properties in a different order. How can I do it in matlab?

> classdef Coordinate
>
> ```
> properties
>    east;
>    west;
>    south;
>    north
> end
> ```
>
> end

Comment: Why do you have to do this? Do you even need to use `properties` if you already have them in an ordered list?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is somewhat strange, I would think you were trying to find the index of elements based on the other cell array of string. If so, you may use

```
[~,idx] = ismember(p,x);
```

where

```
p = properties(myClass);
x = {'west','east','north','south'};
```

The variable `idx` contains the order of each element in `x` for `p`